# Maintain coding Standards in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am starting a project with CodeIgniter framework with a team of 5 members. I have seen the coding standards document. Team will try to maintain it. But still errors may happen. Is there any tool to check the coding standards of Codeigniter and measure performance of this framework after the application is developed. Is there any rule set to be followed in Codeigniter and what documenter should be used along with codeIgniter?

Comment: I don't know about a tool but this may be a help http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are absolutely want to be sure that source adheres to the style guides, you can try hook up the [PHP_CodeSniffer](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.php.php-codesniffer.php) project int your scm's (i'm sure you will use one) `pre-commit` or `pre-receive` hook (this is what [svn](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch05s02.html)/[git](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) calls it). This way you can throw back commits that doesn't go trough the style checking.

One a little less draconian way could be to set up some kind of continuous-integration server like [jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) (there's a [handy template](http://jenkins-php.org/) for php projects) and display some alert when codesniffer alerts style deviations.

However this will make you team to write "whatever the compiler allows" style. With genuine concern about readability and maintainability this will be all useless.

#### Update

As it seems, someone already started to implement sniffer rules against codeigniter's own coding style guide, see the [forum thread](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/180084/), and [github repo](https://github.com/thomas-ernest/CodeIgniter-for-PHP_CodeSniffer).

Comment: can i configure it such that it adheres to Codeigniter standards

Comment: I guess it should be. There's a [tutorial](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.php.php-codesniffer.coding-standard-tutorial.php) on how to write your own standards, however i've never tried to implement CI's own guidelines myself. [This thread](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/180084/) might prove itself useful.